# The Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin version 1.3.10

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle

I've been trying to import a repo from GitHub into Android Studio and I've been having issues with gradle. It has prompted me to update a few things and I have but I'm still receiving an error:

ERROR: The Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin version 1.3.10 and higher.
The following dependencies do not satisfy the required version:
root project 'MathScan-master' -> org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.2.51
Update plugins
Affected Modules: MathScan-master-app

Comment: Looks like all you need to do is update the version of the Kotlin Gradle plugin. The latest at the time of writing is 1.3.72.

Comment: How do I update it?

Comment: update the version in build.gradle file